# UITableView cell are overlapping

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I'm implementing a tableView with section index. where my tableViewCells are overlapping whenever the rows are more than one in any particular section.

Here is my code.

```
![- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return \[self.keys count\];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
//    return \[\[\[UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation\] sectionTitles\] objectAtIndex:section\];
    return \[keys objectAtIndex:section\];
}

- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
//    return \[\[UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation\] sectionIndexTitles\];
    return keys;

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    return \[\[UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation\] sectionForSectionIndexTitleAtIndex:index\];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = \[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil\];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = \[\[UITableViewCell alloc\] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier\];

    }
    \[self.exhibitorTableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)\];

    UIView* bgview = \[\[UIView alloc\] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1)\];
    bgview.opaque = YES;
    bgview.backgroundColor = \[UIColor colorWithRed:244.0f/255 green:245.0f/255 blue:246.0f/255 alpha:1.0\];
    \[cell setBackgroundView:bgview\];
    cell.textLabel.font = \[UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-Light" size:17\];
    cell.detailTextLabel.font = \[UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-Light" size:13\];
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = \[UIColor clearColor\];
    cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = \[UIColor clearColor\];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = \[UIColor colorWithRed:93.0f/255 green:94.0f/255 blue:94.0f/255 alpha:1.0\];

    UIImageView *defaultImage = \[\[UIImageView alloc\]init\];
    \[defaultImage setFrame:CGRectMake(5.0f, 5.0f, 40.0f, 40.0f)\];
    \[cell addSubview:defaultImage\];

    for (int i=0; i<\[self.exhibitorArray count\]; i++) {
        NSString * string = \[\[self.exhibitorArray objectAtIndex:i\]valueForKey:@"name"\];
        NSString *firstLetter = \[string substringToIndex:1\];
    if (\[\[keys objectAtIndex:indexPath.section\] isEqualToString:firstLetter\] ) {

    NSString *urlString = \[\[NSString alloc\]init\];
    urlString = @"http://";
    urlString = \[urlString stringByAppendingString:\[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",\[\[self.exhibitorArray objectAtIndex:i\]valueForKey:@"image"\]\]\];
    NSLog(@"%@",urlString);

    AsyncImageView *asyncImageView = \[\[AsyncImageView alloc\] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 40.0f, 40.0f)\];
    \[asyncImageView setBackgroundColor:\[UIColor clearColor\]\];
    NSString *tmp_string = \[\[NSString alloc\]init\];
    tmp_string = urlString;
    \[asyncImageView loadImageFromURL:\[NSURL URLWithString:tmp_string\]\];
    \[defaultImage addSubview:asyncImageView\];
    defaultImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    tmp_string = nil;
    asyncImageView = nil;
    defaultImage = nil;

    NSString *name_string = \[\[NSString alloc\]init\];
    name_string = \[\[self.exhibitorArray objectAtIndex:i\]valueForKey:@"name"\];
    NSLog(@"%@",name_string);
    UILabel *user_name = \[\[ UILabel alloc\]init \];
    \[user_name setFrame:(CGRectMake(58, 5, 270, 25))\];
    \[user_name setBackgroundColor: \[UIColor clearColor\]\];
    \[user_name setText:name_string\];
    \[user_name setFont:\[UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-Light" size:14\]\];
    \[user_name setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft\];
    \[user_name setTextColor:\[UIColor colorWithRed:93.0f/255 green:94.0f/255 blue:94.0f/255 alpha:1.0\]\];
    \[cell addSubview:user_name\];
    user_name = nil;
        }
    }

    \[cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator\];

    return cell;
}
```

[image]

Comment: remove cell identifier in    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They're not overlapping. You are adding an additional label each time the cell is used.

You need to only add one label to a cell and then reuse that label instead of adding a new one each time.

The same is true for the image views etc...

You're best solution is to use a custom UITableViewCell subclass... http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/

**Possible solution**

Note: I don't like this because of the use of the tag property but it will get it done without subclassing UITableviewCell...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];

    UIImageView *defaultImageView;
    UILabel *customLabel;

    if (cell == nil) {
        // create the cell and empty views ready to take the content.
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        defaultImageView = //create the image view
        defaultImageView.tag = 3;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:defaultImageView];

        customLabel = //create custom label
        customLabel.tag = 4;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:customLabel];
    } else {
        // get the views that have already been created
        defaultImageView = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:3];
        customLabel = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:4];
    }

    // now populate the views...

    defaultImageView.image = someImage;
    customLabel.text = @"Hello, world";

    return cell;
}
```

This way you are only creating one label and one image view in the cell and then reusing it propelry.

Comment: yeah i'm thinking the same. i think i'm running a loop which is creating this issue but i can't remove that loop also.

Comment: yeah. i want to do it without custom cell.

Comment: @Zac24 ok, edited with some rough code. Hopefully that should point you in the right direction.

Comment: I tried but i'm getting an error in these lines `[cell.contentView addSubView:defaultImage];` and `[cell.contentView addSubView:user_name];` "No visible interface 'UIView' declares the selector 'addSubView'".

Comment: @Zac24 Try a lower case 'v' I don't have code completion here :P

Comment: @Zac24 also, you can do this bit by bit so maybe just do the label first to see how it works.

Comment: yeah. i tried this and now it's overlapping but it is giving same output for all rows for that particular section. this is my code now. 
http://pastebin.com/EqmdDkg3

where should i post my output pic so that u can have a look at that

Comment: okay sure. Is there any way i can upload image too. (anything like pastebin for images)

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/dm3ltru5a3ryl4q/iOS%20Simulator%20Screen%20shot%2025-Mar-2014%204.25.30%20pm.png

this is the image link.

  And for code try this link now- http://pastebin.com/hqQPbYHC

Comment: @Zac24 I made a typo in the loop you need to use `nameString` not `string`.

Comment: @Zac24 ok, reading through the code. What you have written will only ever produce the same output for each row of a section. In your code "If the first letter of this object is the same as the index latter then use this object". Perhaps you should be using the `indexPath.row` to get the object from the `exhibitorArray` instead of the loop?

Comment: i checked your paste bin and i din see that u've used string, u used nameString only. And yes i should use indexPath.row to get the object instead of using loop. But first i'm going to try your paste bin solution and let you know.

Comment: i read you code, you have taken two variable as asyncImageView and you 're trying to loadImageFromURL with UIImageView datatype. is it possible to do? I'm asking ? coz this line is inside the loop `AsyncImageView *asyncImageView = [[AsyncImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5.0f, 5.0f, 40.0f, 40.0f)];`

Comment: @Zac24 Which lines? There is only one variable `asyncImageView` declared on line 7... AH! That should be `AsyncImageView` sorry (again, not using an IDE here so I don't have compiler warnings etc...). And yes, line 17 should be `asyncImageView = ...` sorry.

Comment: i did this but one issue is that you have removed "for"loop but along with that loop you also removed the "if" condition which i was using to get the correct data for every section, Now every it populates the data from index 0.  check this out https://www.dropbox.com/s/w1209yfeawej2tv/iOS%20Simulator%20Screen%20shot%2025-Mar-2014%204.57.15%20pm.png

Comment: Your data model needs to be set up correctly. Please show `NSLog(@"%@", self.exhibitorArray);`.

Comment: @Zac24 you should set your data up in sections like the table is.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/0Vp4dpMs   This is my data for `NSLog(@"%@", self.exhibitorArray);`  I guess i used loop just coz of this issue.

Comment: Hmm...you should have your data set up like this ideally... http://pastebin.com/ge7qeZNf

Comment: this data m getting from server and using JSON Parser to parse it.

Comment: @Zac24 Doesn't mean you can't juggle it around to make it easier to work with :) that's the beauty of working on mobile. You don't have to stick to a given structure. When you get the array from the server go through it once to sort it into an array of arrays groups by first letter. Doing the work there once makes dealing with it a lot easier everywhere else :D

Comment: Just go through the array. If the name begins with a new letter create a new array and drop the old array into self.exhibitorArray. Should be too hard.

Comment: you mean create a "new" array if i do that i would end up creating 26 arrays if i've all the alphabets.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Nothing wrong with that. You still have the same number of objects.

Comment: But you only ever need one `self.exhibitorArray` this will just contain the other arrays. You don't have 26 properties for the different letters.

Comment: well that's the total different implementation. i can do that later but for now isn't it possible in the same code by putting for loop. coz when i used for loop i was getting right data in my log for every row of each section but label was getting overlapped.

Comment: No, you were getting 3 labels in the section that had 3 rows, 4 in the sections that had 4 etc... You were getting the "correct" information because you were getting ALL the information. You need to find a way to get ONLY the exact bit you need. That's where a new data storage comes in. You could do it in a loop it would be very clunky though. You'd have to count how many first letters you'd found. and only take the correct one (1st, 2nd, 3rd) based on the row you are trying to display.

Comment: Best of luck. If I helped answer your question then please accept the answer.

Comment: you helped a lot for sure. but still i came back to the same problem again.. :) can u just help me to get this thing done with loop for now . i'll follow the proper way later may be tomorrow or something.

Comment: i tried this but what this is doing is like. if there are more than one row in any section it is just displaying the data in first cell of that section rest are just left blank, no data in those cells.

Comment: Have a go at fixing it then. You are a programmer after all aren't you? :)

Answer (score 0):

Change the line `UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];` with `UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CellIdentifier];`

**Edit**

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


        UIView* bgview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1)];
        bgview.opaque = YES;
        bgview.tag = 8888;
        bgview.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:244.0f/255 green:245.0f/255 blue:246.0f/255 alpha:1.0];
        [cell setBackgroundView:bgview];

        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-Light" size:17];
        cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-Light" size:13];
        cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:93.0f/255 green:94.0f/255 blue:94.0f/255 alpha:1.0];

        UIImageView *defaultImage = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
        [defaultImage setFrame:CGRectMake(5.0f, 5.0f, 40.0f, 40.0f)];
        defaultImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        defaultImage.tag = 7777;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:defaultImage];

        UILabel *user_name = [[ UILabel alloc]init ];
        user_name.tag = 9999;
        [user_name setFrame:(CGRectMake(58, 5, 270, 25))];
        [user_name setBackgroundColor: [UIColor clearColor]];

        [user_name setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-Light" size:14]];
        [user_name setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
        [user_name setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:93.0f/255 green:94.0f/255 blue:94.0f/255 alpha:1.0]];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:user_name];

        AsyncImageView *asyncImageView = [[AsyncImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 40.0f, 40.0f)];
        asyncImageView.tag = 6666;
        [asyncImageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [defaultImage addSubview:asyncImageView];
    }
    [self.exhibitorTableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
    UIImageView *defaultImage = (UIImageView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:7777];
    UILabel *user_name = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:9999];
    AsyncImageView *asyncImageView = (AsyncImageView*)[defaultImage viewWithTag:6666];
    for (int i=0; i<[self.exhibitorArray count]; i++) {
        NSString * string = [[self.exhibitorArray objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"name"];
        NSString *firstLetter = [string substringToIndex:1];
        if ([[keys objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] isEqualToString:firstLetter] ) {

            NSString *urlString ;
            urlString = @"http://";
            urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[self.exhibitorArray objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"image"]]];
            NSLog(@"%@",urlString);
            NSString *tmp_string = urlString;
            [asyncImageView loadImageFromURL:[NSURL URLWithString:tmp_string]];
            NSString *name_string = [[self.exhibitorArray objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"name"];
            NSLog(@"%@",name_string);
            [user_name setText:name_string];
        }
    }

    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I've tried this if i make this change then my whole tableView start getting overlap while scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Thats just because you are creating new labels on every cell datasource method just change

just alloc and add label in

```
if (cell == nil) {
        cell = \[\[UITableViewCell alloc\] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier\];

 **//Allocate label here and set tag**

UILabel *nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initwithframe];
[nameLabel setTag:212];

}

 **get label here by tag and set text on it here.**

eg 

UILabel *nameLabel = [cell viewWithTag:212];
```

Similarly add imageview inside condition and set images on that outside

Answer (score 0):

Because of this line `[cell addSubview:user_name];`  It've added multiple times.To avoid this, try below:

```
UILabel *user_name  = [[ UILabel alloc]init ];
user_name.tag = SomeTagValue;
.
.
.
.
UILabel *preView = [cell viewWithTag:SomeTagValue];
[preView removeFromSuperview];
[cell addSubview:user_name];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding both `cell.TextLabel` and another Label (Named: `user_name`). If you want a custom table cell with imageview and label you can see [this](http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/).

As you can see in your output that label is overlapping. Its not the same label these are different labels in a cell. Hope this helps.. :)

**Edit: Try this:**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = \[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil\];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = \[\[UITableViewCell alloc\] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier\];

    }
    \[self.exhibitorTableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)\];

    UIView* bgview = \[\[UIView alloc\] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1)\];
    bgview.opaque = YES;
    bgview.backgroundColor = \[UIColor colorWithRed:244.0f/255 green:245.0f/255 blue:246.0f/255 alpha:1.0\];
    \[cell setBackgroundView:bgview\];

    UIImageView *defaultImage = \[\[UIImageView alloc\]init\];
    \[defaultImage setFrame:CGRectMake(5.0f, 5.0f, 40.0f, 40.0f)\];
    \[cell addSubview:defaultImage\];

    for (int i=0; i<\[self.exhibitorArray count\]; i++) {
        NSString * string = \[\[self.exhibitorArray objectAtIndex:i\]valueForKey:@"name"\];
        NSString *firstLetter = \[string substringToIndex:1\];
    if (\[\[keys objectAtIndex:indexPath.section\] isEqualToString:firstLetter\] ) {

    NSString *urlString = \[\[NSString alloc\]init\];
    urlString = @"http://";
    urlString = \[urlString stringByAppendingString:\[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",\[\[self.exhibitorArray objectAtIndex:i\]valueForKey:@"image"\]\]\];
    NSLog(@"%@",urlString);

    AsyncImageView *asyncImageView = \[\[AsyncImageView alloc\] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 40.0f, 40.0f)\];
    \[asyncImageView setBackgroundColor:\[UIColor clearColor\]\];
    NSString *tmp_string = \[\[NSString alloc\]init\];
    tmp_string = urlString;
    \[asyncImageView loadImageFromURL:\[NSURL URLWithString:tmp_string\]\];
    \[defaultImage addSubview:asyncImageView\];
    defaultImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    tmp_string = nil;
    asyncImageView = nil;
    defaultImage = nil;

    NSString *name_string = \[\[NSString alloc\]init\];
    name_string = \[\[self.exhibitorArray objectAtIndex:i\]valueForKey:@"name"\];
    NSLog(@"%@",name_string);
    UILabel *user_name = \[\[ UILabel alloc\]init \];
    \[user_name setFrame:(CGRectMake(58, 5, 270, 25))\];
    \[user_name setBackgroundColor: \[UIColor clearColor\]\];
    \[user_name setText:name_string\];
    \[user_name setFont:\[UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-Light" size:14\]\];
    \[user_name setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft\];
    \[user_name setTextColor:\[UIColor colorWithRed:93.0f/255 green:94.0f/255 blue:94.0f/255 alpha:1.0\]\];
    \[cell addSubview:user_name\];
    user_name = nil;
        }
    }

    \[cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator\];

    return cell;
}
```