# App crashing after opening many times UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am using many UITableView in my project. I have created it's customize cell at run time means I designed every cell with UILabels and UITextFields and some more objects at run time. Data is coming from web service. So, when i am opening that UIViewController with UITableView , it is creating new cells(I am not reusing cells because of cell overriding issue).So, after opening those pages many times my app get crash. It is not crashing when i am running it through Xcode.If anyone know how to solve this issue

```
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}
```

Comment: "I am not reusing cells because of cell overriding issue". Would you please expand on that? Seems to me like memory issues due to not reusing cells.

Comment: You have to pass the identifier in place of `nil`. It is creating the cells everytime the controller is loaded. That is why you app is crashing due to memory issues.

Comment: `UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];` wy u are not reusing , replace nil by `cellIdentifier` say for example `UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: cellIdentifier];`

Comment: @AdeelUrRehman: I know but issue is overriding.When i am scrolling UITableView it's overriding cells.So, I put nil instead of cellIdentifier.

Comment: what kind of issue you are facing while the cells are being overriden? And how you are working with those cells please update your post with the code.

Comment: @AdeelUrRehman: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22631003/uitableview-cell-are-overlapping please check this URL.I was facing same problem.So, I used nil instead of cellIdentifier

Comment: Why you want to add a label every time in UITableViewCell as cell already has its label and imageview.

Comment: @AdeelUrRehman: sorry Adeel but it's not my design..it's only issue which i was facing.

Comment: what I get from your description is that you are going to show different kind of cells on the basis of data coming from the web-service. You can solve this by designing every cell nib based. You created models from the data coming from the web-service now create cells on the basis of models.

Comment: There will be some kind of property in the model on the basis of which you will distinguish the creation of cell and the cell identifiers.

Comment: @AdeelUrRehman: Thank you very much Adeel.I was waiting for this solution.My Senior friend told me the same thing but I was not sure.Thank you very much once again.

Comment: @chaaruu no worries. Do let me know if you find any difficulty implementing the solution.